# Using recordselect gem, how can I specify scope or selection parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Users model has a boolean field `show_in_list`. I'm using a `recordselect` widget to present a popup selection window that allows paging through a potentially lengthy list of users.

```
<%= record_multi_select_field ‘users’, @selected_users, 
:controller => ‘/users’, :params => {'show_in_list' => true} %>
```

The first data fetch URL includes the `show_in_list=true` parameter and yields the correct (limited) set of users.

```
/reports/users/browse?show_in_list=true&search=
```

However, clicking the Next button causes a fetch without that parameter resulting in browsing the entire set of users.

```
/reports/users/browse?page=2&search=&update=1
```

Is there a way to configure recordselect to work around this apparent bug? Or can I pass the parameter differently or use a scope somehow?

rails (4.2)
active_scaffold (3.4.99)
recordselect (3.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

This is, indeed, a bug in recordselect 3.6.0. The fix was merged [here](https://github.com/scambra/recordselect/pull/15).

Use

`gem 'recordselect', :git => 'https://github.com/scambra/recordselect.git'`

in your Gemfile to include the pre-release version with the fix, until a new >3.6.0 release is cut.